# Can Salesforce function as a "data warehouse?"

Tags: integration, data, database

I am attempting to integrate on-premises software with our Salesforce Org. Our timekeeping system uses a PostgreSQL database to store time entries committed by staff. Salesforce's role is relegated to CRM and Project Management functionality. Unfortunately, these two systems do not communicate.

I wanted to move timekeeping to Salesforce, but consensus on the web is that Salesforce is not fit to be a "data warehouse." I'm lead to believe that simple but record-intensive information such as timekeeping would likely lead to data bloat. Is this a correct statement?

That said, if I were to integrate the two systems, is my only option to use the existing APIs or an integration service? My understanding was that all of these services (Boomi, Jitterbit, etc.) use the APIs under the hood. And, would doing so not cause me to hit API limits rather quick for near real-time integration?

Comment: Have you looked into Heroku at all?

Comment: Heroku has two issues from my vantage point. 1) it sits somewhere in between IAAS and PAAS where you don't have the out-of-box templating and object creation that SF offers. This means I would have to implement all UI elements myself or hire a UI developer. 2) after speaking with engineering support @ dreamforce, I was told that using Heroku connect still counts against API limits. So, Salesforce integration in near real-time still becomes expensive from an API standpoint. Finally, I would want to use Lightning Connect, but $4,000/mo. per node is rather expensive in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

The data storage in salesforce is costly and also once an object has very huge number of data ,you will see lot of issues either when you code in Apex or do a Visualforce ,or in query performance ,List views or reporting .Please note I am assuming data of 10 million in single table .

Also it depends on at what rate your data size grows inside your table and whether you have archiving mechanism in place.Best practice is to keep only transactional data inside salesforce and not keep data only for read only views .

For huge data prefer using BULK API .Almost all the tools like Informatica cloud,jitterbit or boomi use Bulk API for huge data loads .Bulk API has a limit as well on no of batches one can execute in 24 hrs period .This is a rolling period governor limit and hence this would reset automatically .